# ¿Cómo puedo agregar días a una fecha en un procedimiento almacenado?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

Estoy tratando de agregar días a una fecha en un procedimiento de tienda, pero la fecha lo convierte en un solo número y le sumo los días a ese número, es decir:

```
Declare fecha date;
Declare fechas int;
SET fecha = '2022-02-24';

SET fechas = (fecha + 31);
```

Y me devuelve: **20220255**

Aunque si declaro fechas como date:

`Declare fechas date;`

**Me devuelve: '0000-00-00'**

**¿Cómo hago para que devuelva '2022-03-27'?**

Comment: Estas seguro que los dias se agregan asi en mysql? miraste la documentacion sobre como maneja las fechas la DB?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer uso de `DATE_ADD`, que se traduce como “Agregar a fecha“:

```
select DATE_ADD('2018-01-01', INTERVAL 31 DAY);
```

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó así.